# Create string from exsting string in which every character is represented by * and only space represented by space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to generate a new string from an existing string.`javascript` In the new generated string all characters would be presented by '*' except ' ' (space).
For example if existing string is

"hide me"

then new genrated string would be

`"**** **"`

I tried like this, but it is not working.

```
 function hiddenData()
{
var size = word.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= size; i++)
{
    if (word[i] == ' ') {
        hiddenStr[i] = ' ';
    }
    else
    {
        hiddenStr[i] = '_';
    }
}
hiddenStr[i] = '\0';
}
```

Sorry for my poor explanation,

Comment: There are two major issues with that code. 1. The condition on your `for` loop is incorrect, it should be `i < size`; when `i == size` you'll have gone past the last character of your string and get an error. 2. The variable `i` is only in scope for the `for` loop, you can't use it in the line after that: `hiddenStr[i] = '\0';`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist there are no block-scope variables in JS yet (see `let` keyword), `i` is perfectly available. And accessing a too large `i` won't error, it just returns `undefined`.

Comment: Your function should receive `word` as parameter and return `hiddenStr` as result, rather than magically altering some global variables.

Comment: @Prinzhorn Ahh, you're right. I'm too used to working with Java, and for some reason today decided JavaScript worked the same way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `replace()` and regular expression.

```
var str=word.replace(/[^ ]/g, '*');
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a regular expression

```
alert(word.replace(/[^ ]/g, '*'));
```